# Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

I have a Spring-boot application deployed in docker container within in AWS ECS cluster.

My application stack is => Spring Boot -- JPA -- MySQL RDS

Initially application is deployed and accessible through EC2 public IP.

But after few minutes only application is Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor' and restart container again. it is happening constantly in every 3/4 mins.

I am not getting this kind of error in local deployment connecting to same RDS.

Here is my application.properties

```
server.port=8192

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://multichannelappdatabase.cvjsdfsdfsdfsfs.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/multichannelappdb
spring.datasource.username=xxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver


spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 10000
spring.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow=true 
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

and here is my cloudwatch log

```

16:20:50
2019-05-02 16:20:50.514 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8192 (http) with context path ''

16:20:50
2019-05-02 16:20:50.516 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.api.app.runner.UserManagerApplication : Started UserManagerApplication in 9.338 seconds (JVM running for 10.291)

16:20:57
2019-05-02 16:20:57.117 INFO 1 --- [nio-8192-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

16:20:57
2019-05-02 16:20:57.117 INFO 1 --- [nio-8192-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'

16:20:57
2019-05-02 16:20:57.131 INFO 1 --- [nio-8192-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Completed initialization in 14 ms

16:23:19
2019-05-02 16:23:19.253 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-4] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

16:23:19
2019-05-02 16:23:19.254 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

16:23:19
2019-05-02 16:23:19.257 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...

16:23:19
2019-05-02 16:23:19.274 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Need suggestion to resolve this issue.

Still getting the same issue .. any solution will be helpful

Comment: Hod did you resolved your issue ? What was the root cause ?

Comment: did you find the cause ?

Answer (score 6):

Probably your health-checks are not setup correctly.
AWS is regularly trying to reach your application on a endpoint certain . If this port/path is not reachable or replies with an error, AWS will restart the container.

Find your Load-Balancer (even if you use ECS it's on the EC2 Dashboard).

- Under "Instances" you will find instances of your container marked as unhealthy.
- Under "Health check" you can edit the health check to talk to the correct Port/Url. Make sure it is reachable on your container (and in case of http(s) it should answer with 200 on plain requests).

Answer (score 1):

I have this same symptom under docker swarm when the hosting infrastructure is running out of memory or cpu, random processes are killed, containers are terminated .

Comment: How did you fixed it ?

Comment: do not remember if I fixed it sorry

Comment: never mind I increased swap memory on my node and issue got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar symptom, the problem was solved for me by resolving the liveliness and readiness checks.

Answer (score -2):

Just try to run main class (class containing main method). Right click on this class and simply run this.

Comment: He's app is deployed on aws, he's not getting this kind of error in local deployment connecting to same RDS