# Springboot shutdown after two hours

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-rds

Hi I have springboot running in linux server connecting to RDS oracle and its getting stopped after two hours for the below reason and we couldnt find out exact reason for the same:

```
2020-07-31 13:54:52.865 DEBUG 28836 --- [nio-8023-exec-7] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json, application/cbor]
2020-07-31 13:54:52.866 DEBUG 28836 --- [nio-8023-exec-7] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [[SCM_COUNTERPARTY, SCM_ADMIN, FOX_SYSTEM, SCM_ENV, SCM_EXCEPTIONS, SCM_EDIT_FIELD, SCM_TRADE_STATE_R (truncated)...]
2020-07-31 13:54:52.885 DEBUG 28836 --- [nio-8023-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK

    2020-07-31 16:06:22.296  INFO 28836 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
    2020-07-31 16:06:22.313  INFO 28836 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Comment: Where is this Server deployed ? Is that EC2 instance ?

Comment: Yes it's deployed in Ec2 Instance

Comment: is this link helpful ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55956801/11244881

Comment: Could it be that the EC2 instance is shutting down and it is causing spring boot shutdown ? Is this the current behaviour ?

Comment: My ec2 instance is up and running but the problem is only with springboot which is getting shutdown. I am assuming that it's issue with health check port no configured in load balancer. I will check and confirm.Thanks